# Pivotal Tracker "Finished" vs "Delivered"

Tags: workflow, pivotaltracker

While other story states are self-explanatory, I'm not quite sure what is the intended use of 2 distinct `Finished` and `Delivered` states.

I have watched the videos on the Pivotal website, but found them unhelpful - they just state that we *can* mark the story using those states, but does not explain how does it relate to the workflow.

So, why do we need them? What happens after the developer marks the story as `Finished` and before it gets `Delivered`?

I assume the following workflow:

- A developer starts to work on the story, marking it as `Started`
- Once the story tasks are completed and it passes the unit tests - it is marked as `Finished`
- After ??? it is marked as `Delivered`
- Then, after QA it can be `Accepted` or `Rejected` and restarted, if necessary.

Should we mark the story as `Finished` before some other kind of testing and then `Delivered` once it passes? Or maybe it should involve code review? Perhaps this is a common knowledge in agile/scrum world, that I am yet unaware of?

I do understand that this mostly depends on the conventions, established in the project, but I am looking for some best practices, since we are just starting to incorporate Pivotal Tracker into our workflow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just had this same question and watched [those same videos you did](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/articles/quick_start/), but also found  [a more detailed article on Tracker's workflow](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/articles/tracker_workflow/).

Based on their explanation, I have modified your steps as below.  Obviously everyone is going to have slightly different takes on this, but I've tried to see things through the way your company might work based on your initial steps.

- A developer starts to work on the story, marking it as `Started`
- Once the story tasks are completed and it passes the unit tests - it is marked as `Finished`
- Once the code is successfully deployed to the stage or test environment, it is marked as `Delivered`
- Then, after QA it can be `Accepted` or `Rejected` and restarted, if necessary.

Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Is there any way to add more current_state values ? I mean Start, Code Review, In Code Review, QA, In QA, UAT READY etc ?

Answer (score -1):

That's an old subject, but here's what we are doing in my company :

- When a developer ends a ticket, he finishes the story.
- Any finished story has to be reviewed by another dev
- If the code review is okay, the code is merged to the testing branch
- Then the requester delivers it